# how to dynamically load a script (node js)

Tags: javascript, node.js

So, in my nodeJS server part I need to use function from js file. This file often updated, so i need dynamic load this file every time, when client load page. How I can do this? Thanks!

Answer (score -8, accepted):

This very simple script make me happy :)
github.com/isaacs/node-supervisor

first:

```
npm install supervisor -g
```

second:

```
supervisor myapp.js
```

I have some error, but it's works.

Comment: Very poor explanation! What kind of erros did you got?

Comment: why is this accepted?

Answer (score 7):

Loading code from other files is done with `require`. However, once you've `require`'d a file, requiring it again will not load the file from disk again, but from a memory-cache which Node maintains. To reload the file again, you'll need to remove the cache-entry for your file before you call `require` on it again.

Say your file is called `/some/path/file.js`:

```
// Delete cache entry to make sure the file is re-read from disk.
delete require.cache['/some/path/file.js'];
// Load function from file.
var func = require('/some/path/file.js').func;
```

The file containing the function would look something like this:

```
module.exports = {
  func : function() { /* this is your function */ }
};
```

Comment: so, i have this
http://i.imgur.com/7BHePHS.png
http://i.imgur.com/85TigEB.png
and this not working :(

Comment: `require.cache` probably contains the full path name, `console.log(require.cache)` somewhere to find out how exactly your file is stored in it.

Answer (score 7):

In addition to @robertklep answer, here solution for any path:

```
const path = require('path');

var lib_path = './test' // <-- relative or absolute path                                                                  
var file = require(lib_path);

const reset_cache = (file_path) => {
    var p = path.resolve(file_path);
    const EXTENTION = '.js';
    delete require.cache[p.endsWith(EXTENTION) ? p : p + EXTENTION];
}

// ... lib changed                                                                                                             

reset_cache(lib_path);
file = require(lib_path); // file changed
```

Unfortunately, all dependencies of reloaded file didn't reload too.

Also, you can use [clear-require](https://www.npmjs.com/package/clear-require) module:

```
const clear_require = require('clear-require');

require('./foo');
// ... modify
clear_require('./foo');
require('./foo');
```

it can clear all modules, and handle regexp.