# running tests via lambda (serverless)

Tags: aws-lambda, architecture, google-cloud-functions, serverless

Suppose I have a code snippet and test covering the code (jest here is just an example).

Is it possible

define a test as a lambda/cloud function:

```
const sum = require('./sum');

test('adds 1 + 2 to equal 3', () => {
  expect(sum(1, 2)).toBe(3);
});
```

and code snipped is landed on s3/gcp cloud storage:

```
function sum(a, b) {
  return a + b;
}
module.exports = sum;
```

the function will be listening to an event ( file is stored on the particular folder ) and execute the test code.

the output will be stored back to the file on s3/GCP cloud store or send via API.

**My Question**: Is it possible to implement this scenario using serverless (lambda/cloud functions) and yes where to start from. (Any examples, links, materials).

Thanks.

Comment: Hi, just wanted to make things a bit clear. Where is your "particular folder" being stored, is it inside a storage bucket? What kind of event will trigger the function? Here's a link to know more about triggers and events in Cloud Functions https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/concepts/events-triggers

Comment: Yes, in a storage bucket. I thought it is the most straightforward way to do it but if there is a better option for the use case, please share.

Answer (score 1):

From what I understand, your function will fetch code from a storage bucket. That would introduce more latency because code is loaded on start up and fetching code dynamically from other sources (like a bucket) will add additional latency so I wouldn't recommend it. On serverless, you should always aim that your requests are completed as fast as they can.

Is it possible to do? Yes as I have asked from others and said that Javascript is dynamic enough to do that. But then again, note the consequence. Unless you have a very specific use case, it's not a very ideal approach if I were you.

However, here's what I've came up. You could try to [download](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/downloading-objects#code-samples) your code from Cloud Storage using client libraries and put it on `/tmp`:

> Take note that this is the only directory where you can [write files](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/concepts/exec#file_system) and it will store it on memory.

Then load the downloaded resource from your serverless function. I haven't fully tested how to do it however [here's a thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14911684/how-to-dynamically-load-a-script-node-js) that shows you how.